# Roblox Studio: frame not fading out

Tags: button, roblox

I am making a main menu in Roblox Studio. When I press on play, it moves down, but the background doesn't fade out.

Here's my code:

```
--Define variables

local button = script.Parent
local frame = button.Parent

local function fadeOut(object)
for newTrans = 0, 1, 0.1 do
        wait(0.1)
        object.BackgroundTransparency = newTrans
    end
end

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()

--Get positions
local xScale = button.Position.X.Scale
local yScale = -1
local xOffset = button.Position.X.Offset
local yOffset = button.Position.Y.Offset

--New position
local newPos = UDim2.new(xScale, xOffset, yScale, yOffset)

--Indicate when the tweening is finished
local done = false

local function ended()
    done = true
end

--Tween button
button:TweenPosition(newPos, "Out", "Quad", 1, true, ended)

--Wait for tweening
repeat
    wait(0.1)
until done

    --Fade out the frame
    fadeOut(frame)
end)
```

The code for the fade out is at the top that says: local function fadeOut(object)

in that function the fade out happens.

Thank you for advance,

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

If you have a callback function to call once the tween is done, why don't you call `fadeOut` in your `ended` function?

```
-- Tween button
local allowOverride = false
button:TweenPosition(newPos, "Out", "Quad", 1, allowOverride, function()

    local frame = button.Parent
    print("Finished tweening button. Fading out ", frame.Name)

    -- next, tween the transparency
    fadeOut(frame)

    print("Done fading out , " frame.Name)
end)
```

The code sample you provided was passing `true` to allowOverride. According to https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/function/GuiObject/TweenPosition, that could have allowed another tween that was animating the position to cancel the button's TweenPosition call, which would prevent `ended()` from ever getting called. So your loop would never end.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I tried making my code sample be a modification of the code you provided for your button:TweenPosition code.


If you are getting the error that `BackgroundTransparency is not a valid value for ScreenGui`, it may be that button.Parent is not a frame.


Try changing the print statement to be: 
`print("Finished tweening button. Fading out ", frame.Name, ",", frame.ClassName)`

That will tell you what the frame variable actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This post is canceled cause I made up a new idea for the play button instead.

Thank you verry much and I am really sorry,

Jesse